# How to update billing details for an existing card in Stripe Laravel Cashier / Vue App

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm currently using Laravel cashier. I already have the endpoints to create a new card, delete it or set it as a default payment method, but I can't get in the documentation the use to update the credit card information.

I got this method in the stripe backend documentation.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/update

And I don't get anything similar in the documentation of the stripe js.
https://stripe.com/docs/js

Awaiting your answers, thank you very much.

Comment: Updating an existing PaymentMethod is a backend call. You can collect the billing details via a normal form on the frontend, pass those to the backend, then call the method you've mentioned.

Comment: Hi. And isn't there some method of Laravel Cashier I can use to support me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

I solved the problem as follows

> Every payment method has a method called `asStripePaymentMethod` to access the underlying Stripe object.

[Code implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvezh.png)

*The data comes from a form on the front, the structure of the data is displayed in the official stripe documentation.*

through the payment method id, I could access to the payment method object on Laravel Cashier library, and through ORM, I could save the data.

Laravel Version: 7.X

Laravel Cashier Version: 12.2.0

Comment: is it okay to ask for a reference for the official stripe documentation here